# R loop for with grep function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, word-count

Following code does not work:

I would like to loop over a list of word (array mdf) and find the number of occurences for each word in this list (mdf) in another list of words (array mydf). 
Thanks for your feedback!

```
for (x in mdf)
      { print 
      ( length(grep('x',mydf)))
   }
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `x`. It is a variable, and quoting makes it a character vector. Also, what do you mean it does to work? Can you explain what problem you are having? Also, posting some sample input data and expected output data is the best way to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
colSums(sapply(mdf, grepl, mydf))
```

Here is a demo:

```
colSums(sapply(c("a", "b", "c"), grepl, c("a", "a", "b")))
a b c 
2 1 0
```

Which says a, b and c appears 2, 1 and 0 times in the other array.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove the quotes around `x`.

And, try this for exact matches;

```
for (x in mdf) {
tempx=paste("\\b",x,"\\b", sep="")
temp=paste(c(x,length(grep(tempx,mydf))))
print(temp)}
```

If you do not need exact matches;

```
for (x in mdf) {
temp=paste(c(x,length(grep(x,mydf))))
print(temp)}
```